# how I can test my bot after having the deplyer locally (IIS)

Tags: c#, iis, postman, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-language-understanding

I developed my bot with Microsoft bot framework using C # as a language, it works correctly, now I will want to deploy it on my site without going through azure (using the direct line), I searched the internet and I found that it is possible, by deploying the bot with iis, I followed a tutorial afterwards I got this,now i don't know what i need to do to test my bot.

[image]

Comment: Look under "Your bot is ready".  It give URL where to test.

Comment: Yes, I know but I wouldn't want the test in the emulator, I want to test it at the browser level for example beta.core300.com/api/"hi ", I don't know if this is correct or not

Comment: The link is for an application api/messages.  If you have parameters they would go after a question mark at end of URL like http://localhost:3978/api/messages?id=1234

Comment: Applying what you said is what I got
"upgrade to webstocket is required"

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/64277/how-to-upgrade-to-websocket.html

Comment: While searching on the internet I found this https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-web sockets I will try to apply it and see what it gives

Comment: Your link link doesn't change anything.  It just explain things. There is a negotiation that occurs between client and server.  HTTP has a few modes like version 1.0 (stream) and 1.1 (chunk mode).  And the application layers of to be compatible between client and server.  right now there seems to be an incompatibility issue between client and server and webpage above says you need an update.

Comment: If you can explain to me more, I'm stuck

Comment: I don't know enough about the bot to help a lot.  I just know what the webpage says.  the device may need to be registered.  I can do some more searching on the web, but I think the link above and the messages on the webpage should solve issue.

Comment: You speak on this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/64277/how-to-upgrade-to-websocket.html

Comment: Yes.  The URL is HTTPS (Secure on new link) which uses TLS for authentication.  The above picture is HTTP (not secure).  So you may be having a TLS issue.  What version of Net are you using.

Comment: . Net core 3.1 this is the version

Comment: The recommendation for TLS is to use Net 4.7.2 or newer and target Core 3.1.  There are issues with older version of Net targeting Core.  Then with Net 4.7.2 you can either use Net for TLS or the Operating System for Net.  It is recommended using the operating system in the config settings.  Then the Operating System has to be compatible with TLS version.  So on mobile devices you have to make sure the kernel version support the tLS version.

Comment: OK, I will check

Comment: The easiest way is to use a sniffer like wireshrk or fiddler.  TLS occurs before the HTTP Request.  So if you see the Request than TLS is working.  If TLS fails then you start by checking the TLS version.  You have tagged as Postman.  Does Postman work?  You can compare working Postman TLS version with your c# TLS version.